# Find probabilty

Tags: probability, statistics

I have this table of information:

[image: table of info here]
<sub>(source: [rit.edu](http://www.cis.rit.edu/people/faculty/montag/vandplite/images/chapter_5/contab.gif))</sub>

Probabilities: 
\begin{array}{c|c}
.919 & ????\\\hline
???? & .274
\end{array}

How do I find the probabilities of the question marks? I thought each row and each column was supposed to equal $1.0$, but clearly this won't work.

$1 - .919 = .081$, and $1 - .274 = .726$. However if I fit this in like this, then the rows don't add up (only the columns do):
\begin{array}{c|c}
.919 & .726\\\hline
.081 & .274
\end{array}

Comment: Are you sure that it is not only the rows that should add up to $1.0$? It may help if you say what each row/column represents.

Comment: probability of what? What is that table supposed to represent?

Comment: The problem states:  p(HIT) = .919 and p(CR) = .274. Here is an image of what the probabilities represent: http://www.cis.rit.edu/people/faculty/montag/vandplite/images/chapter_5/contab.gif

Comment: I think only the rows should add up to $1$, since the different rows are conditioning on different things. I'm not completely sure though, so perhaps re-read your notes or textbook if you can? Good luck.

Comment: @majmun Okay thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use rule of complement of conditional probability which states:

$P(A^C/B) = 1-P(A/B)$

Thus

$P(Y/SN)+P(N/SN) = 1$

$P(Y/N)+P(N/N) = 1$

You have $P(Y/SN) = 0.919$

Thus $P(N/SN) = 1-0.919 = 0.081$

You have $P(N/N) = 0.274$

Thus $P(Y/N) = 1-0.274 = 0.726$

Answer (score 1):

This is necessarily true:

- $P(No |Present)=1-P(Yes|Present)$
- $P(Yes|Absent )=1-P(No |Absent )$

This is **not** necessarily true:

- $P(Yes|Absent )=1-P(Yes|Present)$
- $P(No |Present)=1-P(No |Absent )$

So your table should look like this:

$
 \begin{array}{c|c}
  0.919 & 0.081\\
 \hline
  0.726 & 0.274\\
 \end{array}
$